# Performance based count for total number of users registered

Tags: php, mysql, performance, count

What is the best way to keep track of the TOTAL NUMBER OF USERS REGISTERED in terms of performance?

```
select count(id) from user_table
```

OR

- Create a table which stores number of users registered and every time a new user registers, increment the value by 1.

The total number of users registered will be displayed on the Admin Dashboard.

If there is any other way to do it, i would love to know.

Comment: Caching! cache the total number of users in memcached object "or what ever mechanism you like" and when a new user registers reset that object with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create another table for that.

Just do `Select count(id) from user_table` it's just fine

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Would it be right to run this query every time the website admin checks the total number of user on his dashboard

Comment: @Tabby Yes of course it'd be alright. It's not a big SQL query and very common in most application. You can go for it without worries ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `count` exist to accomplish your request:

```
Select count(id) from user_table
```

If you create another table, at every new registration you need to alter the table and increment the value, costing one operation every time a user register.

Answer (score -1):

I have already commented on this but i think that posting it as an answer would fit better.

When it comes to performance, the first think one might think of is "Caching", you can simplay store the total number of users in a caching object "something like [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)" and read from it instead of database, when a new user registers you may reset the value of that object with the new one.

Comment: This is a new way better than creating a new table. Any reference on how to capture that data or how to do it?

Comment: I have already pointed to memcached in my answer but here it is again http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php